# Creating a tag input box like on Stack Overflow using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, controls

How can I build a tag text box thing like here on Stack Overflow using Ruby on Rails?

Also, how do I handle the form post scenarios once the tags are submitted?

Answer (score 4):

If you will take a look on the tags on Stack Overflow - it's just an anchor with span inside for removing it. And of course, you need to style it.

```
<a href="#">My Tag
    <span>X</span>
</a>
```

As for posting the form: Use jQuery and an Ajax request to post it to the server. More information is in *[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)*.

Source code for a demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/Fj3zx/6/.

Also check out the [Choosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) for jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

The [Meta Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Meta_Stack_Overflow) question *[Can I use the tag textbox script?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102510)* might help.

It points people towards the plug-in *[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)*.